Hibernate - Batch update returned unexpected row count from update: 0 actual row count: 0 expected: 1 but im using .save() only
I was wondering why I am having this issue when I am only doing a .save() on the db? I cannot figure this one out for some reason.
my Entity:
@Component
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class mySQLTable {

   @Id
   @Column(name="text_id")
   private int text_id;

   @Column(name="curr_timestamp", insertable = false)
   private String curr_timestamp;

   @Column(name="text")
   private String text;

}

my Repository:
@Repository
public interface TextRepository extends JpaRepository<mySQLTable, Long> {
    public List<mySQLTable> findByTimestampBetween(@Param("start_time")String 
    start_time, @Param("end_time") String end_time);
}

my Service:
@Component
public interface TextService {
   TextRepository saveText(TextRepository text);

   List<TextRepository> fetchTextList();

   List<TextRepository> fetchTextListByTimestamp(String start_time, String end_time);

   TextRepository updateText(TextRepository text, Long departmentId);
 }

my Service Implementation:
@Component
public class TextServiceImpl implements TextService {

  @Autowired
  private TextRepository textRepository;

  @Override
  @Transactional
   public mySQLTable saveText(mySQLTable text) {

     return textRepository.save(text);
   }

  @Override
  public List<mySQLTable> fetchTextList() {

    return textRepository.findAll();
  }

  @Override
  public List<mySQLTable> fetchTextListByTimestamp(String start_time, String end_time) 
  {

    return textRepository.findByTimestampBetween(start_time, end_time);
  }

 @Override
 public mySQLTable updateText(mySQLTable text, Long departmentId) {

    return null;
 }

}

Listener:
public void receiveMessage(String msg) {
  try{

        text.setText(msg);

        mySQLTable textResponse = textService.saveText(text);

        if (textResponse.getMessage() != null || textResponse.getMessage() != "") {
            logger.info("text saved");
        }
  }
  catch (JpaSystemException jpaex) {
      logger.error("Exception while inserting message : "+ jpaex.toString());
    }
  catch(JmsException jmsex) {
      logger.error("JMS Exception while consuming message : "+ jmsex.toString());
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {
      logger.error("Error while consuming message : "+ ex.toString());
  }

I inherited this code and seems to be weird to me that this happens on an update which is not being used anywhere in the code. I also checked in the logs that the message we received in the message queue is being inserted correctly in the db and this error seems to be not being thrown in every message we receive and insert but the error occurs daily.

Maybe you have to use persist method because some time there is no line in database.

It is strange indeed.
I think the JPARepository's save method performs an update if the entry already exists.
By any chance is the message being processed twice?
Can you use the following How can I log SQL statements in Spring Boot? to log the SQL and share? It might provide some clues.

yes, I see some messages being processed twice/thrice. Sample log DEBUG 144 org.hibernate.SQL - update mysqltable set text=?, curr_timestamp=? where text_id=?
